# grantpermissions option is not working in safari browser in mac. is there any alternative for granting camera and microphone?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have tried to grant camera and microphone access using play wright .

the code I used is ...

```
await context.grantPermissions(['camera', 'microphone']);
```

but it is not working.

> Unknown permission camera

is displayed. Is there any way to allow permission access for camera and microphone for safari browser?

I tried

```
await context.grantPermissions(['camera', 'microphone']);
```

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+unknown+permission - try https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/20563